# How can i cange the domain of a Website using a Bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript

How can i cange the domain of a Website using a Bookmarklet?

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H6n1aK0ZSo

replace *www.youtube.com* with *invidio.us*

> https://invidio.us/watch?v=0H6n1aK0ZSo

I havent found anything i understood, since im compleatly oblivious to javascript and i hope that im not bothering you too much.
thank so much you in advance!

Comment: `window.location` has everything you need (+ maybe some `String.prototype.replace()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only thing you care about is the querstring, you can set the domain and add the querystring from the current location.

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com" + window.location.search
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

[pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) allows you to modify the URL displayed in the address bar, but it is restricted to the same origin.

And JS in the browser can't make one URL proxy another at all.